# Authentication problem on access MySQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

I'm moving an old application between two windows server (see data below).

I keep attention to have php.ini, my.ini, httpd.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf alligned.

I know, PHP version is too old and even worse the code use *mysql_connect*.

On the old server the instruction `mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'my_password');` works without problems.

On the new server the same istruction gives *Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)*.

If I call the function without password, the connection works.

I access phpmyadmin with root and my_password.

User root has Password YES, Global privileges ALL PRIVILEGES, Grant YES.

Someone have a suggestion (other than upgrade PHP and connection library) where to look for the problem?

Systems setup:

**Old server**

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Apache 2.4.23
- PHP 5.6.25
- MySQL 5.7.14

**New server**

- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Apache 2.4.41
- PHP 5.6.40
- MySQL 5.7.28

Comment: I think this might better be asked over at [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), although it might also fall under [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), too

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while and doing some test, I used the "workaround" to uninstall wamp and reinstall the exact same version (wamp server 3.0.6 with 3.0.8 update) and align the config files.

Now the app goes without problems.